# How to control the Reader ACM1252 RF Field using C#?

Tags: c#, smartcard

I want to turn off the RF Field, and I also found the command to try, but it doesn't work, it returns 01 63 01, but when I try another command,it works, so I don't know what is wrong with it.

My steps:

1. SCardEstablishContext
2. SCardListReaders
3. SCardConnect(Direct Mode)
4. SCardControl

My code:Turn off RF field

```
SendBuff[0] = 0xFF;
SendBuff[1] = 0xC2;
SendBuff[2] = 0x00;
SendBuff[3] = 0x00;
SendBuff[4] = 0x02;
SendBuff[5] = 0x83;
SendBuff[6] = 0x00;
    
SendLen = 7;
RecvLen = RecvBuff.Length;
    
int pcBytesReturned = 0;
    
retCode = SCardControl(hCard, Control_Code, ref SendBuff[0], SendLen, ref RecvBuff[0], RecvLen, ref pcBytesReturned);
```

[Relevant manual snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ATh.png)

The command I found to turn off RF Field as described in chapter 5.2.3.2 of the document : https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/7948/REF-ACM1252U-Z2-1.06.pdf

Can someone help me to figure out why this command doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a wrong zero byte at the end. This command returns nothing, so it can't be an LE and I don't see another reason for it, since the manual clearly states 1 byte of data.

```
SendBuff[4] = 0x01;  
SendBuff[5] = 0x83;  

SendLen = 6;
```